# Clarification on Outer Measure (Folland)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

On page 29 of Folland's Real Analysis for an outer measure $\mu^*$ a set $A \subset X$ is called $\mu^*$-measurable if

$$
\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^C)
$$

for all $E \subset X$.

Folland goes on to say that the inequality

$$
\mu^*(E) \leq \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^C)
$$

is obvious and holds for any $A$ and $E$.  I don't understand exactly how this is obvious though, am I missing something about the outer measure/sets in general that makes this assertion trivial?

Comment: $E=(E \cap A)\cup (E \cap A^c)$ and the outer measure is subadditive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be any set $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c),$

$$m^*(A)=m^*((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c))$$

$$m^*(A)\leq m^*(A\cap B)+m^* (A\cap B^c)$${ By subadditive property of outer measure.}

I am leaving this proposition( subadditive property) to prove.
*Proposition: If $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is any countable collection of sets, disjoint or not , then
$$m^*(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^*(E_k)$$*